# Reliable software for organizing notes

Tags: database, note-taking

I'm looking for software which can help me organize all my categorized notes or pages (private data, links, thoughts etc) in exportable database. Preferable freeware or crossplatform.

Comment: Cross-platform: For which operating systems? And as it’s just a preference: which OS is required to be supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cherrytree (https://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/) is a flexible cross-platform note-taking application that can store its data in a SQLite database.